# When I flush the toilet it leaks between the bowl and the tank. How do I fix it?

Tags: toilet

This only happens when I flush and the leak is small.

Answer (score 3):

There is a rubber gasket that goes between the tank and the bottom of the toilet.  This is sold in a kit that also includes the bolts for the tank because these bolts are almost always completely rusted and can't be reused.  Be ready to cut the bolts if the nuts will not come off and be careful not to crack or damage the toilet.

[image: Toilet repair kit]

*[Sample repair kit](https://www.lowes.com/pd/plumb-pak-rubber-3-5-in-in-toilet-gasket-repair-kit-for/1000617987)*

Since you are taking the toilet completely apart, it probably makes sense to also replace the fill valve and the flapper.  These are also sold as a kit for around $20.

Comment: It is *possible* that you could stop the leak by simply tightening the two bolts that secure the tank to the bowl. But just snug the bolts; don't over-tighten! The next level of repair would be to change the rubber seals, without separating the tank from the bowl and without changing the seal. To do that turn off the supply valve and flush the toilet. Remove one bolt, put on new rubber washers, and tighten to snug. Then repeat on the other side.

Comment: Those are good options - I just normally see the bolts rusted so bad that none of that would be possible.  Check the condition of the bolts and if they are not too bad, give that a shot for sure.

Comment: You could change the bolts too without detaching the tank from the bowl.